# Git, Gitolite, Deploy and Linux Permissions

Tags: linux, git, deployment, permissions, gitolite

I have an application using some template files and some developers wich are producing them.

The best way I found to mantain templates is to install git over gitolite and creates an hook to automatically checkout templates on update, in the right folders.

Well, everything on setup is up and running fine, but I have a security question.

Templates are used by a small application running with a user called runtime, with runtime group. 
Gitolite uses another user/group usually git:git to manage repositories.

In the hook I must check out files into a runtime user folder and obviously it does not work.

I think about changing git group to the same of runtime, but I really don't know if there are security troubles in this solutions or there are no reasons to worry.

I'm not a security experts, but I know here is full :)

Thank's a lot, David.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you don't actually want to run the checkout of the files from the hook, you just want the hook to trigger them.  The checkout really wants to be run as the `runtime` user?

I can think of a couple of ways to do this, none of them sound amazing:

1. Set-up a passwordless ssh key for the `git` user, so it can run `ssh runtime@localhost ~runtime/doUpdates.sh`, and said script does the `fetch` and `checkout`.
2. Set-up limited `sudo` for the `git` user so it can run `sudo -u runtime ~runtime/doUpdates.sh`.
3. Set-up limited `sudo` for the `git` user so it can `chown runtime:runtime -R` the result of its checkout actions.

And a couple of even worse ones. :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but finally I assigned the same group to both users and give the group write permission to that folder only.